# Expiration of superadmin.p12 certificate

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

I have a super admin certificate which expired two days ago. When I try to click on the Administration tab in my EJBCA instance to renew this certificate, I am getting an error like certificate has expired. Can you guys help me out on how to renew the certificate without the GUI? Is this the problem impacting the Administration tab in my EJBCA instance? After renewing the certificate, does these have any impact on ROOT CA and or any other end entities?

Comment: Maybe Super User or Server Fault sites would be a better place for this question?

Answer (score 1):

From the directory where you've installed EJBCA:

```
./ejbca.sh ra setuserstatus superadmin 10
./ejbca.sh ra setclearpwd superadmin <MY PASSWD>
./ejbca.sh batch
```

where `<MY PASSWD>` is your **new** password.

Comment: Does this impact any already created certificate authorities or end entities?